# Oauth 2 : Spring Boot - Separate Resource server protecting Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices

For my recent project, I have created a separate resource server using spring boot. Resource Server is configured in a way that it will check for 2 legged and 3 legged access to an API and also validates the JWT token. Resource server is an independent spring boot jar running in its container.
We have created several microservices using Spring Boot which are executable jars, deployed and running independently in their container. Resource server will protect end points exposed in these microservices. For that, I have created a RestController in resource server in which end point is exposed which will call the microservice end point when request comes in. for e.g 
**Microservice.java** - Running at port 8080

```
@RequestMapping("/getUser")
public String getUserName(){
   return "xyz";
}
```

**Resource Server** - Running at port 8090 
ResourceServerController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/userInfo")
public String getUserName(){
 // calling above microservice using rest template
}
```

There can be several end point in a several microservices and as we have to protect them, is it right to proxy every end point in the rest controller of a resource server? I am not sure whether it is a correct approach. Other approach which we think of is to create a jar of resource server and deployed as a dependency with every microservice. In this way, we do not need to proxy end points in the Rest Controller of Resource Server.
Just wanted to know the best way to Protect microservices using separate resource server.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing Libraries is not a recommended option. A huge benefit of Microservices is independence and that would go for a toss if you do this.

A better option would be to see if you can provide access to API based on scope. That way, when your Authorization Server issues JWT token, it sends all the applicable scope for the user.

Then, in your Resource Server(s) , you can enable access to Microservice using the following annotation in Spring Boot

```
   @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
```

Another approach is, you can create roles and PreAuthorize using Roles.

If the above options doesn't work out, the current approach that you are following based on Proxy Service is perfectly fine. Only aspect that you should consider is to see if the JWT token validation can be moved to the respective Microservices so that all your services are protected.

Again, Code duplicacy is perfectly fine when you are implementing Microservices and if that is your main concern, don't hesitate to add the same logic in every service. With Microservices, Duplication is better than wrong abstraction

Comment: Checking scope whether user has access or not is not a problem for us. Anyways, we will be doing that and I am clear on that. Our Resource Server validates JWT, that validating logic will be duplicated across various microservices if I don't go by proxy way but then question comes to my mind, what is the need of resource server then?

Comment: Resource Server is your actual microservice where your API(s) are hosted. One of the functionalities it has is the validation of JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is the self-contained token, which can store scope of access for REST-service users. JWT is issued by the Authorization server.In your Resource servers, you should validate every request from REST-service users.  If your Resource server(s) runs on spring-boot you can use the following annotation:

`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_VIEW')")`

As for the part where your services call each other, there no need to use JWT because no REST-service users involved. 
Microservices can be secured by simple BasicAuth, CORS or locate them in one network without access from an external network

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about avoiding duplicate validation code in every micro service which resource server does. I want to keep that logic at one place and looking for best way to achieve it.